# Call functions dynamically in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a dynamic form who change with the route param `this.$route.params.editor` and everything work fine but the submit function does not call the API (the calling function is in a separate file) because also the function is dynamic and change with the params
There are the form code:

```
methods: {
  save () {
    const editor = this.$route.params.editor
    this.$api[editor]().save(this.localData).then((res) => {
      this.localData = res
    }).catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
}
```

The result must be like this:

```
this.$api.material().save(this.localData)
```

or

```
this.$api.item().save(this.localData)
```

But the function must be obviusly dynamic

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Have you tried logging it via `console.log(editor, this.$api[editor], this.$api[editor]())`? What was the result?

Comment: It will work, as long as $route.params.editor and $api are what you expect. What is the question? I'm voting to close because it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: The error is `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$api[editor] is not a function`

Comment: Try my console log and tell us wha it outputs